# What's the right way to monitor systemd services status

Tags: systemd, monitoring, notifications, tray

I'm trying to figure what's the right way for me to be notified when some systemd service is having problems. Manually checking `systemctl status` isn't a sustainable option; at the very least I want to have a simple tray icon, like just green or red. Some sounds and/or visual notifications can be useful too. Surprisingly I don't seem to find any existing tools for that, so the best I can think of is to write my own, maybe some simple bash script which would poll systemctl once in a while, and update the icon status.

Pretty poor but alas.

Before I actually start spending time on that, want to make sure, am I by any chance missing some better options?

Comment: systemd has a dbus interface which you can use to subscribe to events -- see `dbus-monitor` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl --type=service

sudo systemctl --state=active  

sudo systemctl --state=failed 

journalctl -b -p err
```

These should be enough to monitor and to find any misbehaving services.

Comment: Your answer assumes I'm gonna be executing those commands manually, but as I mentioned in my question, checking it manually isn't a sustainable option. I have better things to do, you know; and I just need some status icon plus ideally some visual+sound notification when something breaks. And when I get that notification, _then_ I'm going to get logs etc.

Comment: @DmitryFrank so your computer will play marche funebre, you will start fixing the service, then immediately after, you will get a support call and tell them you are on it.

Comment: @DmitryFrank So put it in `cron`.

Comment: What's the point of having that in cron @TrippKinetics? Those commands simply print something out, for the caller to read it and figure what to do with it. So if we want to have it in cron, at the very least we should also have something to parse the output, and then do _something_, like enable or disable a tray icon.

Comment: @DmitryFrank If your cron job outputs, the output is emailed to the address that is configured for that purpose in cron, usually `root`.

Comment: Yeah that's technically an option, but I just don't agree that emailing logs that I have to check manually is a good way to monitor services. I have better things to do than reading emailed logs every day; I want the computer to check things for me and let me know when there's a problem. In fact I already implemented a tool to show a simple green or red tray icon, hopefully I'll find the time to polish it and then will share it on github.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `check_systemd`  command line tool from the Nagios monitoring plugin  collection. You can just call this without parameter or setting up Nagios (which is a hell to do).

On Ubuntu you only need to call:

```
sudo apt -y install monitoring-plugins-systemd
```

and then you can check

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_systemd
```

If `$?` is 0 all is ok, if 1 its bad and 2 if its critical

All other return values should tell you to get the heck out because the world is on fire.